# Change the biblatex citation style alphabetic

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How would I cite the book as `[GABC]` instead of as `[Gr+]`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade and A. Author and B. Buthor and C. Cuthor",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
 \labelelement{
  \field[final]{shorthand}
  \field{label}
  \field[strwidth=2,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
  \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
}
% \labelelement{
%  \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
% }
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cite{greenwade93}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxnames` does not control the alphabetic labels, you also want

```
maxalphanames=10
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade and A. Author and B. Buthor and C. Cuthor",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxnames=10,maxalphanames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
 \labelelement{
  \field[final]{shorthand}
  \field{label}
  \field[strwidth=2,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
  \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
}
% \labelelement{
%  \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
% }
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cite{greenwade93}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course this will still give [Gre+] for works with more than 10 authors. It will also give [ABCDEFGHI] for works with 9 authors, so the label length gets out of hand.